# Ошибка при парсинге сайтов

Tags: javascript, node.js, парсер, puppeteer, cheerio

Всем привет . Я писал парсер который бы собирал информацию с goodreads(тут я работаю через api), librarius и labirint . Но при запуске скрипта возникает ошибка .

---

Код:

```
const puppeteer   = require('puppeteer'),
    cheerio       = require('cheerio'),
    goodreads     = require('goodreads-api-node'),
    {key, secret} = require('./config/Goodreads.json'),
    myCredentials = {key: key,secret: secret},
    gr            = goodreads(myCredentials);
let books         = [],
    titles;         

async function PreSearch(word){
    let gb = await gr.searchBooks({q:word, page:"1", field:"all"});
    gb = gb.search.results.work;
    gb.forEach((item, i) =>{
        books[i] = {id:++i, title:item.best_book.title}
    })   
    titles = books;
    return books
}
//let r = PreSearch("Башня ласточки").then(res => console.log(titles))
async function Search(arr,i) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
    });
    const page   = await browser.newPage();
    --i
    let title =   arr[i].title;
    title = title.toLowerCase();
    title = title.replace(/\s/g,"-");
    let g = title.indexOf('(');
    if(g != -1){
        title = title.slice(0, g)
    }
    const LibURL = `https://librarius.md/ru/search?search=${title}`
    const LabURL = `https://www.labirint.ru/search/${title}/`
    //Поиск книги по либрариусу
    await page.goto(LibURL);
    const content = await page.content();
    const $ = cheerio.load(content);
    let LibrBooks = []
    $('.book__title').slice(4, 36).each((idx, elem) => {
        let titles = $(elem).text();
        LibrBooks.push({titles});
    })
    $('.book__price').slice(4, 36).each((idx, elem) => {
        let price = $(elem).text()
        // Убираем \n
        price = price.substring(price.indexOf("\n") + 1);
        // Убираем пробелы
        price = price.replace(/\s/g,"");
        // перебираем масив и добовляем в объекты значение price
        LibrBooks[idx].price = price
    })
    await page.goto(LabURL);
    let LabrBooks = []
    $('.product-title').slice(4, 36).each((idx, elem) => {
        let titles = $(elem).text();
        LabrBooks.push({titles});
    })
    $('.price-val').slice(4, 36).each((idx, elem) => {
        let price = $(elem).text()
        // Убираем \n
        price = price.substring(price.indexOf("\n") + 1);
        // Убираем пробелы
        price = price.replace(/\s/g,"");
        // перебираем масив и добовляем в объекты значение price
        LabrBooks[idx].price = price
    })
    browser.close();
    let result = [
        LibrBooks,
        LabrBooks
    ]
    console.log(result)
} 
let r = PreSearch("Башня ласточки").then(books => Search(books).then(res => console.log(res)))
```

Ошибка:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
    at Search (D:\Projects\bots\BuyBooks\search.js:26:26)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объявление функции `Search` (она принимает массив и индекс, который по умолчанию равен `undefined`):

```
async function Search(arr,i) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
    });
    const page   = await browser.newPage();
    --i
    let title =   arr[i].title;
}
```

Вызов функции `Search`:

```
PreSearch("Башня ласточки")
  .then(books => Search(books).then(res => console.log(res)))
```

Вызов, как видно, без указания индекса, а значит там, где начинается работа с элементом массива, переменная `i` равна `NaN` - результат декремента, а `arr[i]` равен `undefined`.

---

Но основная проблема тут в абсолютно неструктурированнном коде. Организованный подобным образом код не даст вам нормально разрабатываться.

Делайте функции, выполняющие одно действие. Не используйте глобальные переменные только потому, что не умеете работать с promise.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const goodreads = require('goodreads-api-node');

const goodreadCredentials = {
    key: '...',
    secret: '...'
};

let browser;

(async () => {

  try {
    const bookname = 'Башня ласточки';
    const goodreadBooks = await goodreadSearchBooks(bookname);

    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: true
    });

    for (const book of goodreadBooks) {
      const something = await Search(book);
      console.log(something);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }

  if (browser) {
    await browser.close();
  }

})();

async function goodreadSearchBooks(search) {
  const gr = goodreads(goodreadCredentials);

  const res = await gr.searchBooks({
    q: search,
    page: 1,
    field: 'all'
  });

  const books = (res.search.results.work || []).reduce((acc, w) => {
    const best_book = w.best_book;
    if (best_book) {
      acc.push({
        id: best_book.id._,
        title: best_book.title
      });
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);

  return books
}

async function Search(book) {
  let title = book.title;
  title = title.split('(')[0].split('/')[0]; // замените это на свои кракозябры

  const [ librariusBooks, labirintBooks ] = await Promise.all([
    librariusSearch(title),
    labirintSearch(title)
  ]);

  return { librariusBooks, labirintBooks };
}

async function librariusSearch(title) {
  const url = `https://librarius.md/ru/search?search=${title}`;
  const content = await loadPage(url);
  const $ = cheerio.load(content);

  const books = [];
  // парсинг данных
  return books;
}

async function labirintSearch(title) {
  const url = `https://www.labirint.ru/search/${title}/`;
  const content = await loadPage(url);
  const $ = cheerio.load(content);

  const books = [];
  // парсинг данных
  return books;
}

async function loadPage(url) {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);
  return page.content();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо . Да с промисами я ещё не доконца разобрался . Спасибо за такой рефакторинг . Удачи вам и всего наилучшего .

Comment: А и ещё кое что . Я немного глупый и у меня такие же вопросы . Как мне вызвать главную функцию которая является анонимной ? Просто присвойть её чему нибудь и уже от туда вызывать или есть какие-то другие методы ?

Comment: не заморачивайся сложностями, ты делаешь бота и тебе будет норм дать функции имя и вызвать её по имени